# Send FCM notification to more than 1000 tokens node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have firestore document with 5000+ users token but FCM limit is 1000 how can I send
notification to all.

how can I send 1000-1000 using loop anyone can help me to figure out this.

```js
var newData;

exports.articlenotification = functions.firestore
  .document("Articles/{id}")
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    //

    if (snapshot.empty) {
      console.log("No Devices");
      return;
    }

    newData = snapshot.data();

    const deviceIdTokens = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("Tokens")
      .where("article", "==", true)
      .get();

    var tokens = [];

    for (var token of deviceIdTokens.docs) {
      tokens.push(token.data().token);
    }
    var payload = {
      notification: {
        title: "New Article",
        body: newData.title,
        image: newData.image,
        sound: "default"
      }
    };

    try {
      const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
      console.log("Notification sent successfully");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do it. first way to sent 1000 then 1000 ..etc. and second way by send to specific topic and all clients who subscribe to this topic will receive your notification.

1. [device-group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/device-group)
2. [topic-messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/topic-messaging)

This code to send 1000 then 1000 ..etc. but I don't prefer it. you should use `topic-messaging` instead of it.

```
for (let i = 0; i < listOf5000Tokens.length; i += 1000) {
    const listOf1000Tokens = listOf5000Tokens.slice(i, i + 1000);

    // using await to wait for sending to 1000 token
    await doSomeThing(listOf1000Tokens);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you'll need to send the message in [batches](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-a-batch-of-messages).

For example:

```
// Create a list containing up to 500 messages.
const messages = [];
messages.push({
  notification: {title: 'Price drop', body: '5% off all electronics'},
  token: registrationToken,
});
messages.push({
  notification: {title: 'Price drop', body: '2% off all books'},
  topic: 'readers-club',
});

admin.messaging()
.sendAll(messages)
.then((response) => console.log(response.successCount + ' messages were sent successfully'));
```